# How to add padding between options in select input?

Tags: css

How to add padding to my select input options? Here is my CSS and all options seem below each other without any spacing (in terms of height of option) I have a CSS reset.. aside from that how can I give the options a bit of height to make it look good?

```
.upload-input select {
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #888;
    width: 616px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

**Update**

I applied the suggested css. It does not look right.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `margin-top` and `margin-bottom`?

Comment: can you upload the html?

Comment: Consider creating a jsfiddle test-case. People like to see what currently happens "in action" (including minimal markup) and to be able to well, fiddle with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
.upload-input select option { padding: 6px;}
```

You might have to fiddle with the .upload-input select css though.

Like:

```
.upload-input select {height: 35px;}
```

Comment: OK. Try making it { padding: 6px !important;}

Comment: This seems to add the padding to the bottom of the option. It does not look good (using firefox). how to make the padding.. like in line-height all items below each other with equal spacing from top and bottom.